# MVC Controller not reached from Ajax Jquery POST request

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, post

I am facing problems with sending ajax POST request to MVC controller.

My client code is:

```
     cb.setConsumerKey("x","y");
            cb.setProxy('proxy address'); //indicative
            var id=null;
            var pass= null;
            var jsonObj=null;

                function authorize(){

                    cb.__call(
                            "oauth_accessToken",
                            {oauth_verifier: document.getElementById("PINFIELD").value},

                            function (reply) {

                                    id = reply.oauth_token;                                      
                                    pass = reply.oauth_token_secret;

                                     jsonObj = {
                                                            user: []
                                                    };
                                    jsonObj.user.push({
                "id" : id,
                                    "psw" : pass
                                    });

                                    alert(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: "/OAuthControl",
                                        type: "POST",                                            
                                        data: JSON.stringify(jsonObj),                                     
                                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                        success: function(result) {
                                            alert(done);
                                        },
                                        error: function(xhRequest, ErrorText, thrownError) {
                                        alert(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
                                        }
                                    });      

                            }
                    );


            }
```

whereas the code in the controller is:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(("/auth"))
public class AuthController {

................................................................

@RequestMapping(value="OAuthControl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String OAuthControl(
        @RequestParam String user,
        HttpServletResponse response

){

  //todo

 }
```

I have been struggling a few hours with this, as it seems that controller is never called.
I always get the message defined in the error function.

Comment: you have mapping as /auth but it is not specified in ajax url

Comment: Yes, I noticed and I replaced it with @RequestMapping(("/")), but still does not work.

Comment: try dataType : "json" instead of contentType in ajax()

Comment: I tried it but still bad news :(

Comment: Change RequestMethod.POST to RequestMethod.GET (and remove the user parameter).  Then enter the Url into a web browser directly and see if it hits it that way, it might be that your are running under an application context and has nothing to do with JQuery because your Url is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        cache : false,

        type : "POST",

        url : "/OAuthControl?date=" + new Date(),

        dataType : "json",

        success : function(responseData) {

        },
        error : function(e) {

            alert("Error :"+e);
        }

    });
```

new Date ensures new request is made every time.
Hope this helps